# ios autolayout issue with UILable text padding

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout

I have a custom class created for custom cells for my table view.  There's UILabel for messages.  I'm using storyboard to set the constraints, pinning the label to the top and right side of the table cell, I found that doing this causes the label to resize to fit the content.  Now I can't figure out how to add padding to the label because anything done in cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't work since auto layout is selected.  I've seen many examples that do CGRectMake with float values but they don't work and I think it's because of auto layout.  Is there any solution for this?

I'm not even sure what code to show for this...so here goes something:

How I'm getting the height of the message...the cell is set for 220 width...cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"chatCell";
ChatCell *cell = (ChatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[ChatCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
info = [receivedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
message = [info objectForKey:@"message"];
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(220, 2000);
CGRect rect = [message boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]} context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
```

With that information, I set the table row heights in heightForRowAtIndexPath.  But adjusting the frame of the label cell.messageLabel gives me no result.  Here's something else I tried in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UIView *messageFrame = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, size.height)];
[messageFrame addSubview:cell.messageLabel];
[cell addSubview:messageFrame];
```

But this is the result in the simulator:

[image]

Everything is moved up and the whole text doesn't show.  Is there a simple solution for this or do I have to rethink my entire code?

ANSWER:
What I did was add a UIView in storyboard and put it's constraints to the bottom of the cell.  Since I was adjusting the cell height based on content bounds function from ios7, setting the constraint to the bottom automatically stretched the UIView all the way to the bottom.  Playing with the message label width, I got to have padding.  Hope this helps someone.